# How can I substitute only the second group in my regex match object?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a large data file I want to easily replace values in. Value names are indicated by tags i.e. `<VALUE>` and followed by their respective text/numerical amounts, with each value name on its own line.

I wrote the regex pattern `(r'(<VALUE>)(.*)\n)`. and I want to substitute the second group.

I've written the following code.

```
def edit_attribute():
    with open("file.txt", "w+") as file:
        file_string = file.read()
        attribute_regex = re.compile(r'(<VALUE>)(.*)\n')
        mo = attribute_regex.search(file_string)
        #replace mo.group(2)
```

I tried to use re's sub method but I can't do so without replacing the entire line including the value names.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possibly a lookbehind is what you're looking for: `r'(?<=<VALUE>)(.*)`, now your group $1 needs to be replaced (lookarounds do not consume any characters).

Comment: You don't replace capture groups. You use capture groups to get the part you want to copy to the replacement, and replace everything else.

Comment: Karla, please provide a part of your file and explain what you need to change it into. It sounds as if you need to perform some replacements inside Group 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't replace capture groups. Capture groups are used to capture the part of the string you want to keep. You can then refer to this value in the replacement string with backslash followed by the group number.

```
newstring = re.sub(r'(<VALUE>).*', r'\1foo', oldstring)
```

will produce `'<VALUE>foo'`.